# Sending A List of Strings in json format

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

```
r = requests.post(BASE_URL + uri, params={'nccAdgroupId': 'asr1'}, json=[{'keyword': 'hello'}]
created_adkeyword = r.json()[0]
```

Above code works well.

However, I have to loop through a list and send multiple strings as keyword

so I tried following but it didn't work.

```
newItem = 'first new item'
r = requests.post(BASE_URL + uri, params={'nccAdgroupId': 'asr1'}, json=[{'keyword': newItem}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"? See also [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If your second example did not work as expected, please give us a description of the intended result and the result you got. If there is an error message, please include that as well.